# Check if a Google Sheets cell has protection with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet-protection

How to check if a cell in Google Sheets has protection with Google Apps Script? Specifically, range protection, not sheet protection.

Comment: What if the range is protected only partially? Or you just want to check for single cells?

Comment: Yes, it's easier to check for a single cell.

Comment: Thank you to vstepaniuk for the solution. It's utterly retarded that the Protected class doesn't have a method for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if a cell with coordinates `row` and `col` (starting from 1) has protection use:

```
function has_protection(row,col) { // row and column starting from 1
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell_has_protection = false;      
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); // get all protected ranges
  if ( protections != '' ) {
    for (var p = 0; p < protections.length; p++) {
      var pro_range = protections[p].getRange(); // each protected range
      if (row >= pro_range.getRow()
      && row <= (pro_range.getRow() + pro_range.getHeight() - 1)
      && col >= pro_range.getColumn()
      && col <= (pro_range.getColumn() + pro_range.getWidth() - 1)) {
        cell_has_protection = true;
      } 

    }
  }
  return cell_has_protection;
}
```

You can also highlight all the protected cells on the sheet with the following code (it will clear all other highlights on the sheet and fill only the protected):

```
function color_protected(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();      
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  if ( protections != '' ) {
    sheet.getRange('1:' + sheet.getMaxRows()).setBackground(null); // clear all background on the sheet
    for (var p = 0; p < protections.length; p++) {
      var pro_range = protections[p].getRange();
      //Logger.log(pro_range.getA1Notation());
      pro_range.setBackground('#fbbc04'); // color protected range
    }
  }
}
```