# Check In Static Timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to create a Scripts based static timestamp in a cell based on other cell data.

I have a GoogleSheet for every Month and each Day is a Sheet. I use it to check in new projects from the team. Currently I have column A as a time column and B-G are for client data and everything after that is for inhouse updates. I originally had the team writing in the time that the projects got put into the sheet in column A, but then moved to Formula in A and protected the column from any edits. It's a static time insert so that any data entered in columns B-G a time shows up in column A that remains unchanged when the first piece of data is entered. So if B4 gets data > A4 has a static time > C4 has data, no change in A4. But when all the data is removed (they made a mistake) the time is also removed: D4 is entered, A4 has a time, D4 is deleted, A4 becomes blank.

Current formula -

A4:
=IF(OR(B4<>"",C4<>"",D4<>"",E4<>"",F4<>"",G4<>""),IF(A4<>"",A4,NOW()),"")

A11:
=IF(OR(B11<>"",C11<>"",D11<>"",E11<>"",F11<>"",G11<>""),IF(A11<>"",A11,NOW()),"")

etc.

This works great until someone accidentally deletes a cell and then I get a "#REF" error.

=IF(OR(B12<>"",#REF,D12<>"",E12<>"",F12<>"",G12<>""),IF(A12<>"",A12,NOW()),"")

OR someone drags/copies data across the sheet and then I get weird stuff

=IF(OR(B13<>"",C19<>"",D13<>"",E13<>"",F13<>"",G13<>""),IF(A13<>"",A13,NOW()),"")

So, ultimately I'm looking to put this into a google script or something that will get rid of the #REF errors since I do some backdoor data collection from the timestamp and educating staff on not to delete things hasn't done anything in 6 months.

Example Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15FPaVj8HMqmExIJfOcWrSL5RU3AWTgWzLCxJ9l9flWI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Part of the problem is that the formula is in the same cell that you are evaluating like here `IF(A12<>"",A12,NOW())` - which means that you're not really evaluating it all. Do you have space on this sheet for a helper column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spreadsheet has times in Column A but users don't consistently insert the time when they create new rows of information in the spreadsheet.

You have tried using formulas to counter this, but the formulas reference themselves and, so, are ineffective. Also, the formulas default a value of `=Now` (better than nothing) may not reflect the actual time a row was created.

This script is triggered by a simple `onEdit`. It has several elements:

- is the edit below the data range (row 4)

  - if not, then do nothing
- is the edit is in Column A (time), then check that the value is a date/time.

  - If no, issue a warning and reset the edited cell
  - If yes, then protect the edited cell.
- is the edit in a column  other than A

  - If yes, check whether the value in Column A is a date/time, if not issue a warning, reset the edited cell and position the cursor in Column A
  - If no, and if the value in Column A is date/time, do nothing

I don't pretend that the script is as efficient as it could be (it is NOT) but it provides the OP with a basis to develop to their needs.

**Note:** Cells in Column A should be formatted for Number, Custom date and time:

- Hour (with/without leading zero) : Minute (with leading zero)

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  
  // some variables 
  var firstDataRow = 4
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var range = sheet.getRange(editedRow,editedCol)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited row = "+editedRow+". edited Col = "+editedCol+", range = "+range.getA1Notation())
  var data = range.getValue()
  var editedValue = e.value
  var dateRange = sheet.getRange(editedRow,1)
  var dateValue = dateRange.getValue()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited value = "+editedValue+", data value = "+data)

  // test if the edit is in the data range
  if (editedRow<firstDataRow){
    // edit is not in data range so ignore
    return
  }
  else{
    // #1 - test if data has been entered in Column A (date)
    if (editedCol == 1){  
      // test for date value
      if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(dateValue) !== "[object Date]" ){
        // Col1 value is not a date
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: edit in Column A - edited value - "+dateValue+" is NOT a date")

        // Display a dialog box with a message.
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        var response = ui.alert('INVALID TIME. The time you entered was invalid, Please enter a valid time?', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
        // Process the user's response.
        if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
        } 
        // move cursior back to cell and clear data entry
        dateRange.activateAsCurrentCell();
        dateRange.clearContent()
        return
      }else{
        // Col1 is a date
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: edit in Column A - edited value - "+dateValue+" is a date") 

        // Protect the date
        const me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
        const protection = range.protect()
        protection.getEditors().forEach(user => { 
          protection.removeEditor(user.getEmail())
        })
        protection.addEditor(me)
        // highlight the cell to show protection
        range.setBackground("pink");
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Protection added - now double check")
        // double check that protection is OK
        var protCheck = has_protection(editedRow,1)
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Data range protection : "+protCheck)
        // note trouble-shooting if value returned = FALSE
      }
    }
    else{
        // edit isn't in Column A, so test if Column A already has date
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(dateValue) !== "[object Date]" ){
        // Col1 value is not a date
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: edit NOT in ColA BUT Date value - "+dateValue+" is NOT a date")
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        var response = ui.alert('TIME IS BLANK. You started data entrry without entering time in Column A, Please enter a valid time', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
        // Process the user's response.
        if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
        } 
        // clear the content
        range.clearContent()
        dateRange.activateAsCurrentCell();
        return
      }else{
        // Col1 is a date
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: edit NOT in ColA BUT value - "+dateValue+" is a date") 
        // do nothing
      }
    }
  }
}

/* Sourced from "Check if a Google Sheets cell has protection with Google Apps Script"
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/70328247/1330560
// by vstepaniuk
*/
function has_protection(row,col) { // row and column starting from 1
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell_has_protection = false;      
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); // get all protected ranges
  if ( protections != '' ) {
    for (var p = 0; p < protections.length; p++) {
      var pro_range = protections[p].getRange(); // each protected range
      if (row >= pro_range.getRow()
      && row <= (pro_range.getRow() + pro_range.getHeight() - 1)
      && col >= pro_range.getColumn()
      && col <= (pro_range.getColumn() + pro_range.getWidth() - 1)) {
        cell_has_protection = true;
      } 

    }
  }
  return cell_has_protection;
}
```