# Protect a checkbox until another checkbox is checked in Googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like allow checkboxes in a specific order. Is it possible to protect E2 before C2 is checked. And to protect C2 after E2 is checked.

This would also apply to H2 & J2 and all rows.

[Googlesheets example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuc1M.png)

I tried other scripts on this site and it doesn't allowing a specific order.

Comment: `I tried other scripts on this site` Would you please edit your question to show a script that you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a Google Sheets cell has protection with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70328246/check-if-a-google-sheets-cell-has-protection-with-google-apps-script)